# Wrap MySQL connection with Promise and Finally clause

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, q, node-mysql

I'm currently using node-js, node-mysql, and Q promises. How do I "wrap" the connection in a promise, such that when any function is done using the connection, a "finally" function is called, releasing the connection back into the pool?

Comment: What did you already try?

Comment: I working with a function that returns a promise with a connection to the DB. Now, I'm thinking of having the "getConnection"'s promise conain both a promise (with the .finally callback already specified) and the db connection, and the caller (who's looking for a DB connection) would have to resolve the promise. However, that still doesn't guarantee the promise will ever be resolved, therefor the promise may never call the finally clause.

Comment: It's hard to explain because it's convoluted and definitely not the right way to do it.

Comment: Could you write some code? It will be easier to help you.